# Make Visual Studio 2010 display more lines in code editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

With a 14" LCD monitor (1366x768), my VS2010 can only display 21 lines in code editor. There are too many tool bars occupied upper and bottom part (see below screenshot). When writing codes, it's OK to use fullscreen mode. However, when reading codes, I need some of the toolbar like the bookmark bar, open file tab. Is there any suggestion to increase the viewing area?

[image]

Comment: Remove toolbars and panes? *Tools->Customize* and pane close buttons.

Comment: tip: toolbars can also be placed vertically on the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a single custom toolbar with just the commands you really use in it. Remove the other toolbars. Close tool windows docked at the bottom.

There is an addon that can even remove the menu bar – you'll need to learn keyboard shortcuts (this is a good idea anyway: moving a hand to/from the mouse is much slower).

Answer (score 1):

- Increase secreen resolution
- Use a different font such as `Terminal` or `Consolas`. I guess you must be already using `Consolas`, try `Terminal`.
- Decrease the font size.

Answer (score 1):

Turn monitor by 90 degree, so it is higher not wider.

Besides that - get a decent monitor. 14" is barely legal acording to some european laws for office use. Programmers tyically get a lot bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Customize your toolbars and get rid of the buttons you don't use.  You'll probably be able to fit everything on one row after that.

For example, I don't think I have used the toolbar buttons for cut/copy/paste, using the keyboard instead, so those were the first buttons I removed.

On the right side of each toolbar, there is a button with an arrow, click on that and you should see "customize this toolbar" in the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are having an older notebook, you might not able to change your display, increase your screen resolution or turn the monitor by 90 degrees, like the others suggested. Here are my suggestions for when this is the case:

- Place your toolbars left or right instead at the top or bottom
- close output window
- use fullscreen mode and learn keyboard shortcuts for bookmarks and file menu functions, so you can work without the specfic toolbars

Answer (score 0):

I use Full Screen mode (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to toggle) when doing the actual editing, with only the solution explorer open on the right hand side.